# Display a list of weather info in a table (OpenWeather API)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, thymeleaf

I use OpenWeather API to make an app in which you can search for the city you want to view its weather info(temp,weather description,min temp...). I made this part but i m stuck when i try to add forecast option in which you can see 5 Day / 3 Hour Forecast weather.

[This is what i receive as a response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBMkL.png)

The correct response would display a table that shows every 3 hours weather info but now i receive only one row with one date info.

I tried some loops but didn't work.

**ForecastWeatherController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ForecastWeatherController{


    @Autowired
    private ForecastWeatherService forecastWeatherService;


    @GetMapping("/info/{counterValue}/info/{cityValue}")
    public String getInfo(@PathVariable("counterValue") int counterValue, @PathVariable("cityValue") String cityValue , Model model){

        String name = forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue).getCity().getName();
        double temp = forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue).getList().listIterator().next().getMain().getTemp();
        String desc = forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue).getList().listIterator().next().getWeather().listIterator().next().getDescription();
        double minTemp = forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue).getList().listIterator().next().getMain().getTemp_min();
        double maxTemp = forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue).getList().listIterator().next().getMain().getTemp_max();
        String date = forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue).getList().listIterator().next().getDt_txt();

        model.addAttribute("cityName", name);
        model.addAttribute("weatherTemp", temp);
        model.addAttribute("weatherDesc", desc);
        model.addAttribute("weatherMinTemp", minTemp);
        model.addAttribute("weatherMaxTemp", maxTemp);
        model.addAttribute("weatherDate", date);


        return "home2";
    }
```

**home2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weather API Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Weather Tracker API</h1>
    <p>Search for the city you want to view weather details</p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                City</th>
            <th>
                Temperature Now</th>
            <th>
                Weather Description</th>
            <th>
                Minimum Temperature</th>
            <th>
                Maximum Temperature</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>

        <td th:text="${cityName}">
        <td th:text="${weatherTemp}">
        <td th:text="${weatherDesc}">
        <td th:text="${weatherMinTemp}">
        <td th:text="${weatherMaxTemp}">
        <td th:text="${weatherDate}"/>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**ForecastWeatherService.java**

```
 public interface ForecastWeatherService {
    
        public ForecastWeatherModel getForecastInfoByCity(int counter , String cityValue);
    
    }
```

**ForecastWeatherServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class ForecastWeatherServiceImpl implements ForecastWeatherService{

    @Value("${forecast.url}")
    private String forecastApiBaseUrl;

    @Value("${additional.url}")
    private String forecastApiAdditionalUrl;


    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Override
    public ForecastWeatherModel getForecastInfoByCity(int counter , String cityValue) {

        ForecastWeatherModel result = restTemplate.getForObject(forecastApiBaseUrl+counter+"&appid="+apiKey+forecastApiAdditionalUrl+cityValue+"&units=metric" , ForecastWeatherModel.class);

        return result;
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
 external.api.url=  https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= 
    api.key = ApiKeyExample
    server.port = 8080
    
    # ---------------------------FORECAST---------------------------
    
    forecast.url = https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?cnt=
    additional.url = &q=
```

Do i have to loop inside getInfo method and home2.html or i should make a ForecastWeatherModel List and loop the elements?

Comment: Assuming you have the correct listing of raw data coming back from your API call. don't call `next()` in your weather controller. Instead, pass the iterable data to Thymeleaf, and let Thymeleaf [do the iteration](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#iteration). So, Thymeleaf probably needs to receive a single object - whatever is returned from `forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue)`.

Comment: "_I tried some loops but didn't work._" - Can you be more specific? It helps to show us what you tried, and what happened when you tried it. Do you mean Thymeleaf "loops", or loops in your controller? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting each attribute on, put the entire object on.  Then you can use Thymeleaf to loop through.  For example:

```
@GetMapping("/info/{counterValue}/info/{cityValue}")
public String getInfo(@PathVariable("counterValue") int counterValue, @PathVariable("cityValue") String cityValue , Model model){
  model.addAttribute("forecast", forecastWeatherService.getForecastInfoByCity(counterValue, cityValue));
  return "home2";
}
```

Then, in the Thymeleaf you loop over the same attributes.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Weather Tracker API</h1>
    <h2 th:text="${forecast.city}" />
    
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Temperature Now</th>
            <th>Minimum Temperature</th>
            <th>Maximum Temperature</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr th:each="data: ${forecast.list}">
            <td th:text="${data.main.temp}" />
            <td th:text="${data.main.getTemp_min()}" />
            <td th:text="${data.main.getTemp_max()}" />
            <td th:text="${data.main.getDt_txt()}" />
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```